# Tuple data to Swift key value pair. It is a python object and the response is in single quote string

Tags: swift

I have a tuple data as eg:
[('__cfduid', 'd9d981d5fce8e462bfc46619a32a6af2d1598652071'), ('kf_session', 'qsietP9WQszT7GQpEvsETyIYvAicLVgy')]

I want this in key value pair.

The expected output is
__cfduid=d9d981d5fce8e462bfc46619a32a6af2d1598652071;kf_session=qsietP9WQszT7GQpEvsETyIYvAicLVgy

Comment: Are you trying to initialize a Dictionary with an array of tuples?

Comment: @LeoDabus It is a pythonobject

Comment: Single string with a single line?

Comment: The pythonobject output is [('__cfduid', 'd9d981d5fce8e462bfc46619a32a6af2d1598652071'), ('kf_session', 'qsietP9WQszT7GQpEvsETyIYvAicLVgy')]

Comment: I was asking about the resulting string

Comment: Resulting string to be __cfduid=d9d981d5fce8e462bfc46619a32a6af2d1598652071;kf_session=qsietP9WQszT7GQpEvsETyIYvAicLVgy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
[
   ("__cfduid", "d9d981d5fce8e462bfc46619a32a6af2d1598652071"), 
   ("kf_session", "qsietP9WQszT7GQpEvsETyIYvAicLVgy")
]
.map { "\($0)=\($1)" }
.joined(separator: ";")
```

The idea is to transform your array of `(String, String)` tuples, via `map` into a new array of `String`, then join the final array's elements with semicolons.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But my data is in single quote and it is a pythonobject

Comment: Oh. I see. It might be helpful to mention that in your original question.